# "cannot find symbol" error from makeConcatWithConstants()

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

Error:

```
C:\Users\My\AndroidStudioProjects\StoryApp\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\com\dicoding\picodiploma\storyapp\homeStoryActivity\StoryDatabase_Impl.java:109: error: cannot find symbol
                  + " Found:\n" + _existingTableStory);
                                  ^
  symbol:   method makeConcatWithConstants(Lookup,String,MethodType,String)
  location: interface StringConcatFactory
```

Code:

```
if (! _infoTableStory.equals(_existingTableStory)) {
  return new RoomOpenHelper.ValidationResult(false, "table_story(com.dicoding.picodiploma.storyapp.homeStoryActivity.ListStoryItem).\n"
          + " Expected:\n" + _infoTableStory + "\n"
          + " Found:\n" + _existingTableStory);
}
```

How to resolve the error?

Comment: Could you include your dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

```
File > Project Structure 
Set Source Compability = java 11 (or java >=8 )
Set Target Compability =java 11 ( or java >=8 )
```

The problem is due incompability between Android Studio (which build on java >= 8)  with old java version (v8)